# Icinga check_jboss "NRPE: unable to read output"

Tags: monitoring, nagios, nrpe

I'm using `Icinga` to monitor some servers and services. Most of them run fine. But now I like to monitor a JBoss-AS on one server via `NRPE`. Therefore I'm using the `check_jboss`-Plugin from MonitoringExchange. Although each time I try running a test-command from my Icinga-Server via NRPE I'm getting a `NRPE: unable to read output` error. When I try executing the command directly on the monitored server it runs fine. It's strange that the execution on the monitored server takes around 5 seconds to return a acceptable result but the NRPE-Exceution returns immediately the error. Trying to set up the NRPE-timeout didn't solve the problem. I also checked the permissions of the check_jboss-plugin and set them to "777" so that there should be no error. 
I don't think that there's a common issue with NRPE, because there are also some other checks (e.g. check_load, check_disk, ...) via NRPE and they are all running fine. The permissions of these plugins are analog to my check_jboss-Plugin.

Following one sample exceuction on the monitored server which runs fine:

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_jboss.pl -T ServerInfo -J jboss.system -a MaxMemory -w 3000: -c 2000: -f
JBOSS OK - MaxMemory is 4049076224 | MaxMemory=4049076224
```

Here are two command-executions via NRPE from my Icinga-Server. Both commands are correctly

```
./check_nrpe -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -c check_hda1
DISK OK - free space: / 47452 MB (76% inode=97%);| /=14505MB;52218;58745;0;65273
./check_nrpe -H xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -c jboss_MaxMemory
NRPE: Unable to read output
```

Does anyone have a hint for me? If further config-information needed please ask :)

Comment: When you run check_jboss.pl manually, are you running it as the nagios/nrpe user?

Comment: No, all comments are executed with user "root". Yet there are no special user-configurations.

Comment: It's not a valid test, then. You need to test as the nagios or nrpe user. Also, do any other NRPE checks work, remotely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to rule out SELinux either by disabling it globally or by changing the SELinux type to        `nagios_unconfined_plugin_exec_t`.

Comment: After executing the command "chcon -t nagios_unconfined_plugin_exec_t <check_jboss_plugin>" everything worked fine. Thanks therefore :)